# Use of future progressive tense in a specific context

Tags: meaning-in-context, tenses, future, progressive-aspect

I'd like to ask about a specific use of future progressive tense.

Context:
*I am at a restaurant and I go to the bar to order my food. 
There is a waiter at the bar and he asks whether I am eating at the restaurant or taking away. Then I reply as '**' I will be sitting outside.''** The waiter then replies: ''Please take a seat, we will come to you and take your order.''*

**Instead of simple future tense as such 'I will sit outside', is it correct and natural for a native speaker to use future progressive in this context and say 'I will be sitting outside?'**

If my intention was to guide the waiter where to find me in a large restaurant, while they are looking for me the phrase 'I will be sitting outside' would be appropriate.

However it is a small restuarant where seatings outside are quite visible from inside. Nevertheless, outside is crowded whereas inside is pretty unoccuppied. In order to accelarate my service in case there might be new clients inside that they can take care first, can I stress where I sit this way and use future progressive?

Comment: A fluent speaker would say "I'm sitting outside" (or, less commonly, "I'll be sitting outside") if they know that's where they'll be sitting, or "I'd like to sit outside" (or variations such as *I want to / I'm hoping to*) if their seating isn't certain.

Comment: @Chappo, then I think it sounds natural to use 'I will be sitting outside' regardless of how delibarate I want to guide them to where I sit? They can find me easily no matter where I sit inside or outside in that small restaurant. However in this context I want to give slight meaning that when they are ready to take my order they must take care of seatings outside. I relate where I sit to their action which is being ready and taking orders.

Comment: I'm not sure how "I'll be sitting outside" is an answer to that question, but saying "I'll be sitting outside" as a way to indicate to the waiter that's where you wish to be seated is a common way to say it.  It comes across more strongly but not rudely.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman, it is free to seat without asking when there is available place in that restaurant. If that was a big restaurant using future progressive would indicate a strong guidance for waiter where to find me. Can I still relate where I sit to their action which is being ready and taking orders therefore can I still use future progressive?

Comment: The size of the restaurant is irrelevant!

Comment: @KateBunting, could you please elaborate more as a native speaker?

Comment: You seem to think it would make a difference whether it is a large and busy restaurant or a small one where the staff can easily see you. It doesn't make any difference! You can say "I'll be sitting outside" in either case.

Comment: @KateBunting, ok thanks. Can we then conclude using the phrase 'I will be sitting outside' indicates emphasis for the state of sitting outside; therefore it is stronger and more formal explanation? I just want to understand semantical reasoning of using future progressive tense here.

Comment: No emphasis or formality; it's simply telling the waiter where you will be when he comes to look for you.

Comment: @KateBunting, sorry if I misunderstand you but  if it is observable where I sit in a small restuarant, why should I use future progressive tense to indicate the waiter where I sit? The waiter doesn't even have to look for me. You were telling the size of the restaurant is irrelevant. Thanks again!

Comment: In the scenario you describe, you could say either "I will sit outside" (meaning "That's where I've decided to sit") or "I'll be sitting outside" (when you come to take my order.) The tense has nothing to do with how easy it will be for the waiter to find you, it just means that you will be seated at your chosen table for some time.